# anaconda .conda folder move from /home/usrxy to some other location

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a RHEL server with Anaconda3 installed. Each user in the system gets 2 GiG space in the `/home/` folder and another large folder in a mounted drive. When the user is trying to create a conda environment using `conda create -n my_env` it fills all the .tar files in `.conda` folder and installation breaks. Is there a way I specify a custom location for the `.conda` folder.

Best
Jagan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `--prefix` option [documentation](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-create.html)

Option 1:
If you want to create your virtual environment in current directory then use

```
conda create --prefix=envName python=X.X
```

Option 2: if you want to mention the directory then give full path

```
conda create --prefix=/YourPath/yourEnvName python=x.x
```

Option 3: If you dont want to explicitly mention the path everytime and want all your environments to be stored somewhere else by default, you can set that up in your `.condarc` file [documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-environment-directories-envs-dirs)

You can do this in command line using:

```
conda config --add envs_dirs <path to directory>
```

`envs_dirs` in your `.condarc` file will add an additional location to the package cache search path.

Comment: The `--prefix` will help me in specifying the folder where the new environment will be created. The current issue is when the environment creation in progress it downloads packages and store it in `/home/userw123/.conda/pkgs` . This is the part which creates trouble.

Comment: In that case, when you mention the directory  in your `.condarc` file , it will add an additional location to the package cache search path. Also try making `/home/userw123/.conda/pkgs` directory read-only so that access is denied if conda uses it as first directory to access.

Comment: @Jaganadh did this answer work for your original problem?

Comment: @AjayBisht How to move existing envs to other folder? Can we just simply `mv` all the folders in `~/.conda/envs/` to the desired folder?

Comment: @Jon to move follow this link.  I suggest just uninstall and start over: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/move-directory/

Comment: How to list all conda env under the current working directory? I mean: `conda env list` will not list envs created with `--prefix=relativePath` in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Came across this while having a similar problem with lack of space in my home directory...

Building on Ajay Bisht's solution, to change the package cache search path, you can set

```
conda config --add pkgs_dirs <path to directory>/pkgs
```

as well as

```
conda config --add envs_dirs <path to directory>/envs
```

See here https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-package-directories-pkgs-dirs

Answer (score 5):

I had the same disk space problem.
All docs and forums told me to uninstall and reinstall anaconda to new location...
I didn't want that, so here another approach:

- copy anaconda folder to new location.
  lets assume old location /home/uname/anaconda3,
  new location /home/uname/mountx/anaconda3
  cp -r /home/uname/anaconda3 /home/uname/mountx/anaconda3
- rename original anaconda folder (to be sure its not used later)
  mv /home/uname/anaconda3 /home/uname/anaconda3.bak
- replace all occurrences of "/home/uname/anaconda3" with "/home/uname/mountx/anaconda3".
  do this in new anaconda folder, .conda, .bashrc, and your projects.
  I used PyCharm with no open project to do the replacing,
  sed in a shell might also work
- start new anaconda shell and PyCharm to test it
- remove renamed original anaconda folder afterwards if it works
  rm -rf /home/uname/anaconda3.bak
- done

worked fine like a PyCharm for me :)