# Set a path for the ~/.conda/pkgs directory

Tags: conda

Working on a cluster with very limited space on my home directory, so I want to set the default from the home directory for ~/.conda/pkgs folder to be another directory and I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I have tried using the .condarc file with pkg_dirs:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults

pkg_dirs: my/new/folder

Ideally this would make the creation and installation of the .conda folder in the new path not my home directory
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gained clarity from this post: and will post answer here for anyone trying to Google

[anaconda .conda folder move from /home/usrxy to some other location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957827/anaconda-conda-foler-move-from-home-usrxy-to-some-other-location)

The solution is two-fold:

1. make your .conda folder in home no longer writeable
2. Add the pkg_dirs correctly to the .condarc file by either
   conda config --add pkgs_dirs /PATH/TO/FOLDER

or editing your .condarc directly and using the correct syntax

```
pkgs_dirs:
  - /PATH/TO/FOLDER
```

See [Conda Documentation on setting `pkgs_dirs`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html?highlight=pkgs_dirs#specify-package-directories-pkgs-dirs).

Comment: This really helped my out as my default .conda/pkgs path contains cyrillic username characters which can't be changed on windows

Comment: And FYI, the `.condarc` file is in `~/.condarc` for you normal user. In case it is not there, create it.

Comment: Another option: `export CONDA_PKGS_DIRS=/your/path`