# Is it safe to delete ~/.conda/pkgs

Tags: anaconda, conda, cluster-computing, anaconda-cluster

Does .conda/pkgs directory only contain intermediate download files or the actual packages that my environment relies on? I am mostly using `--prefix` to build environments because of limited home directory space.

Context: considering removing .conda/pkgs but worried it may affect my installed environments' functioning

Related: [Set a path for the ~/.conda/pkgs directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697342/set-a-path-for-the-conda-pkgs-directory)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to manually delete all files in pkgs folder in anaconda python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266229/is-it-safe-to-manually-delete-all-files-in-pkgs-folder-in-anaconda-python) The `~/.conda/pkgs` is also a cache, so the answer there should be applicable, i.e., yes it is safe to delete in hardlinking conditions (the default). In your case, another alternative might be creating a package cache on the non-home filesystem and configure Conda to use it with the `pkgs_dirs` setting.

Comment: Thanks @merv! For others this may help, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957827/anaconda-conda-folder-move-from-home-usrxy-to-some-other-location